# Error while pushing a commit from local to github

Tags: git, github

I am pretty new to this git and github thing and I am at the point of pushing commits on the local repo master branch to the remote github repo. The push works successfully and the remote repo updates accordingly but at the end of the push message I get this lengthy error:

```
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': Unable to create '/Users/ahmedhassan/version-control/reflections/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point you did something in your local repository (`/Users/ahmedhassan/version-control/reflections/.git/`) as some other user—probably `root`, perhaps via `sudo`.  This changed some files there so that they are now owned by the other user, not by you.  You do not have permission to modify the other user's files.

The solution is to set the ownership of those files back to yourself, so that you have permission to modify them.

Comment: How is it possible to set the ownership back to me? Yes I used sudo. Is it by re cloning the repo again?

Comment: You *could* re-clone, but it's probably faster and easier to `sudo chown -R ahmedhassan <path>` (if you're in the right directory the `<path>` part can just be `.`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have unnecessarily used `sudo` at some point while setting up your git repository. I would suggest cloning the repository again from GitHub in a new directory *without* using sudo.

```
git clone https://github.com/ahmedhassan/repository.git
```